# How To Call/Create iPhone Calendar In A User Application

Tags: iphone

I would like to know whether we can create a calendar using NSCalender and show it in our dedicated application. We can create a NSCalender object by

****NSCalendar *japaneseCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier : NSJapaneseCalendar];****

But how can we show this calender in out application. Is there any way to show the default calander in our application when a user click a button.

Please please guide me, i am hanging here for last few days.

Thank You
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

NSCalendar has nothing to with the Calendar app on the iPhone, it's simply a class used to represent a calendar for whatever reason you need one.

I'm not sure that this can be done on the iPhone from within an app.

-

After re-reading your question, I think I misunderstood what you were asking.

If you want to display some kind of calendar view within the app using that particular calendar, you'll have to create you own view and draw the calendar into it.

You may be able to find some code on the internet to accomplish this already.